# xslt - merge some elements and sort them

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml code

```
<realtime_result>
  <team>
    <team_name>real madrid</team_name>
    <events>
      <yellow_card time="28">ronaldo</yellow_card>
      <yellow_card time="31">ronaldo</yellow_card>
      <red_card time="39">benzema</red_card>
          .
          .
    </events>
  </team>
  <team>
    <team_name>Barcelona</team_name>
    <events>
      <goal time="25">messi</goal>
      <red_card time="44">messi</red_card>
      <yellow_card time="63">iniesta</yellow_card>
          .
          .
    </events>
  </team>
</realtime_result>
```

and I need an xslt code to transform it to a table like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>real madrid</th>
    <th>time</th>
    <th>barcelona</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>goal : messi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>yello card : ronaldo</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>barcelona</td>
  </tr>
    .
    .
<table>
```

Note that events are sorted (25, 28, 31, 39, 44 ...).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You might want to go through this link [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..

Comment: Where is the "merge" part? Did you mean to merge two (or more) events in the same time slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example input XML is not valid - the first closing `team` tag is missing, and the events for the second team have the wrong closing tags. Also the desired output is a bit unclear - the first event doesn't display the team name while the second event does. As I guess the team name shouldn't be displayed as it's already in the header, following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="realtime_result">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="//team[1]/team_name"/>
            </th>
            <th>time</th>
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="//team[2]/team_name"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//events/*">
            <xsl:sort select="@time"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:if test="
            parent::events/preceding-sibling::team_name
                                              [
                                                normalize-space()='real madrid'
                                              ]">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),' : ', .)"/>
         </xsl:if>
        </td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@time"/></td>
        <td>
          <xsl:if test="
            parent::events/preceding-sibling::team_name
                                             [
                                               normalize-space()='Barcelona'
                                             ]">
           <xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),' : ', .)"/>
         </xsl:if>
       </td>
     </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the corrected input XML has the ouput

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>real madrid</th>
      <th>time</th>
      <th>Barcelona</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>goal : messi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>yellow_card : ronaldo</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>yellow_card : ronaldo</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>red_card : benzema</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>red_card : messi</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>yellow_card : iniesta</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The events are sorted by time using `<xsl:sort select="@time"/>` when applying templates to the events. The template generating the rows checks for the team name using

```
<xsl:if test="parent::events/preceding-sibling::team_name
                                             [
                                               normalize-space()='Barcelona'
                                             ]">
```

As the input XML doesn't have any spaces at the `team_name`, this could also be written as

```
<xsl:if test="parent::events/preceding-sibling::team_name
                                             [
                                              .='Barcelona'
                                             ]">
```

`normalize-space()` would just remove any leading or trailing whitespace which is sometimes necessary when checking for equality.
The value for the event cell is only written for the team of the current event, and the event name retrieved by using `local-name()`.

For reference: [xsl:sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256196%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [local-name()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-us/library/ms256070%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [normalize-space()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256063%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and as maybe helpful visualization for XPath axes http://www.xmlplease.com/axis

Comment: I would have thought that 'Barcelona' is **data**.